# How to make an object follow a motion path in Universal Windows App

Tags: storyboard, win-universal-app, uwp, blend

I want to make a square follow a curved path in storyboard.
Tried to create a path using the pen tool in `WPF` you can convert it to motion path and all is solved but in `UWP` app this cannot be done.
My question is is there any way to make an object follow a non-linear path using code or Blend for Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Please explain your first approach to reaching a solution, that didnt work well.

Comment: edited the post it should be more clear now thanks for explaining what is wrong with the  post instead of just voting down like the others.

Comment: Sorry for asking, what do UWP and WFP mean? this is context info you may provide to catch  attention of the right experts on the matter.

Comment: well these are acttualy common terms UWP reffers to Universal apps  and WPF  reffers to  a User interface system for windows based apps it is common known for C# developers